# Using plaid with Stripe

Tags: node.js, e-commerce, plaid, stripe-payments

I am trying to build an eCommerce site using Stripe and Plaid to do ACH payment and I am new to both. Is Plaid's role mainly to collect the payment and verify the information? Do I use Plaid in the payout process as well? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plaid handles collecting and verifying information about the customer. Stripe handles the actual ACH transfer part. Plaid is not involved in the payout process. For more info you can check out the docs:

https://plaid.com/docs/auth/partnerships/stripe/

https://stripe.com/docs/ach#using-plaid

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Also, I am curious is it possible to collect and verify payments using Plaid and then payout to a bank account directly without using Stripe?

Comment: Yes! You can use the Plaid Bank Transfers API (https://plaid.com/docs/bank-transfers/), you can use a partner that's not Stripe (a full list is here: https://plaid.com/docs/auth/partnerships/), or you can use some non-partner ACH handling solution. Using Stripe or another partner is very popular, though, esp. for smaller customers.